# Is there a way to set tortoise subversion to show log history date information in local timezone

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN. Currently, when I look at the svn commit history, it shows the date information in UTC. But I am from a different timezone, is there a way to set the timezone to show date information in local/different timezone.

Comment: I wonder if TortoiseSVN uses the same time zone as the system time, i.e your OS is not set to the local time zone.

Comment: my os is set to show the local time, but svn log showed time in UTC.

Comment: Really? According to https://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2003-09/0322.shtml, svn should display logs in local time. What does `Get-TimeZone` return in powershell? Are you using `svn log` in the normal way, from your client repo?

Comment: can't access my machine now, gotta wait till monday, sorry

Comment: Apologies, svn does show the log in local time, i was looking the log in a virtual machine, which had different time zone set in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is that svn *does* show logs in local time; the local time was wrong.